# Debezium SQL Server Source Connectors streams events only once per day

Tags: sql-server, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I am facing a problem where my Debezium SQL Server Source Connectors is not streaming CDC captures in real time but streams all events once per day at the same time `19:07:29`. Below is a sample record

```
      "source":{
         "version":"1.8.1.Final",
         "connector":"sqlserver",
         "name":"dataroom-rds",
         "ts_ms":1655275673757,
         "snapshot":"false",
         "db":"dbDataRoom",
         "sequence":null,
         "schema":"dbo",
         "table":"tblFolder",
         "change_lsn":"0056e213:00000e55:000a",
         "commit_lsn":"0056e213:00000ecd:0014",
         "event_serial_no":1
      },
      "op":"c",
      "ts_ms":1655284049349,
      "transaction":null
```

You see the difference in `source.ts_ms`  and `ts_ms` . `source.ts_ms` is `15 June 2022 16:47:53.757` but `ts_ms` is `15 June 2022 19:07:29.349` . The documentation mentions that it means there is a lag but doesnt give any more info.

https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/connectors/sqlserver#sqlserver-change-event-values

> In the source object, ts_ms indicates the time when a change was
> committed in the database. By comparing the value for
> payload.source.ts_ms with the value for payload.ts_ms, you can
> determine the lag between the source database update and Debezium.

Below is the connector config

```
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
kind: KafkaConnector
metadata:
  name: mssql-connector-dbdataroom-raw
  namespace: kafka
  labels:
    strimzi.io/cluster: kafka-connect-cluster
spec:
  class: io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector
  tasksMax: 1
  config:
    database.server.id: "1"
    database.server.name: "dataroom-rds"
    database.hostname: "${secrets:kafka/dataroom-rds-creds:host}"
    database.port: "1433"
    database.user: "${secrets:kafka/dataroom-rds-creds:username}"
    database.password: "${secrets:kafka/dataroom-rds-creds:password}"
    database.dbname: "${secrets:kafka/dataroom-rds-creds:dbname}"
    table.include.list: "dbo.tblFolder,dbo.tblDocument,dbo.tblAllowedSecurityGroupFolder,dbo.tblAllowedSecurityGroupFolderHistory"
    snapshot.isolation.mode: "read_committed"
    snapshot.lock.timeout.ms: "-1"
    poll.interval.ms: "2000"

    database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers: KUSTOMIZE_REPLACEMENT
    database.history.kafka.topic: "schema-changes.dbdataroom"

    database.history.producer.security.protocol: "SASL_SSL"
    database.history.producer.sasl.mechanism: "SCRAM-SHA-512"
    database.history.producer.sasl.jaas.config: "org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username=${secrets:kafka/kafka-connect-msk-secrets:msk_sasl_user} password=${secrets:kafka/kafka-connect-msk-secrets:msk_sasl_password} ;"

    database.history.consumer.security.protocol: "SASL_SSL"
    database.history.consumer.sasl.mechanism: "SCRAM-SHA-512"
    database.history.consumer.sasl.jaas.config: "org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username=${secrets:kafka/kafka-connect-msk-secrets:msk_sasl_user} password=${secrets:kafka/kafka-connect-msk-secrets:msk_sasl_password} ;"

    transforms: "changeTopicCase"
    # This transform changes the case of tables names to lowercase to match the topic. Table names in SQL Server
    # have uppercase characters.
    transforms.changeTopicCase.type: "com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.transform.common.ChangeTopicCase"
    transforms.changeTopicCase.from: "UPPER_UNDERSCORE"
    transforms.changeTopicCase.to: "LOWER_UNDERSCORE"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hassan , without logs this is difficult to solve. Please check the following and post more logs

1. Check if the CDC is enabled on the tables
2. Query the CDC table in SQL Server , There is a default cdc schema where changes are captured.

```sql
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM cdc.dbo_<TABLE-NAME//e.g.tblFolder>_CT -- add filters on time columns
```

3. The only SMT is a case change , so expect not to have any issues there
4. Check the Kafka connect logs. From the question probably is getting deployed to k8s. Login into the POD

```
curl localhost:8083/connectors
curl localhost:8083/connectors/<connector-name-from-above>/tasks/0/status
```

5. Do you have any other hints on the logs ?
6. Are there issues in the SQL Server ? sp_who2 , sp_whoisactive perhaps for any clue ?
7. Any network issues between kubernetes and the RDS SQL Server ?

While the time correlation may be valid , these would be the ways to find any issues and narrow down what you face

Comment: Hi Ramachandran. Your troubleshooting steps were really helpful. It helped drill down the issue to CDC which you mentioned in point 2. The CDC table is not reflecting the changes instantly which are done in the source table. I am still troubleshooting why it is happening.
There are not failure logs anywhere in kafka connect logs and the connectors look healthy.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the polling interval set for CDC job in SQL Server

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).