# Have problem connecting SQL server to Kafka via Debezium and don't result back in production server whereas test database works good

Tags: sql, sql-server, apache-kafka, debezium

I have a problem with our production database.
CDC in activated in our MSSQL database, both in test and production. But as long as new records store in the test database we receive captured records in our Kafka topic but in the production area, there are no results.
I have a user in the production server with exact same config and properties with
which I have in the test server.
Both with `public` and `db_datareader` user mapping in login properties.
But there is a slight bit of differentiation when I execute the query

```sql
EXEC sp_cdc_help_change_data_capture
```

According to this [Debezium documentation](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/connectors/sqlserver.html#_verifying_that_the_user_has_access_to_the_cdc_table), I should get a result back showing
tables with corresponding CDC capture configurations. So, it returns mentioned result in the test database but I don't get back anything (empty result) in the production database.

Are there any additional settings that I should consider to get appropriate results?

Comment: Hello Mohsen , There are a set of debugging steps i mentioned on this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72639881/debezium-sql-server-source-connectors-streams-events-only-once-per-day . Do you want to run through the list to narrow where the issue is wrto CDC (assuming you have enabled CDC in SQL Server)

Comment: Hi @Ramachandran.A.G , All the properties are configured properly. According to the issue that I mentioned when I receive any new records from the SQL server in production I encounter this which is the Debezium log:

Comment: `ERROR [debezium-|task-0] Skipping change ChangeTableResultSet{changeTable=Capture instance "dbo_**" [sourceTableId=**.dbo.**, changeTableId=**.cdc.dbo_**_CT, startLsn=000153af:00011f37:014a, changeTableObjectId=1425635414, stopLsn=NULL], resultSet=SQLServerResultSet:4424, completed=false, currentChangePosition=NULL(NULL)} as its LSN is NULL which is not expected (io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerStreamingChangeEventSource:219)`

Comment: It solved @Ramachandran.A.G, 
The database administrator should have accessed me `CDCRole`.